# Compilation error in g++ : error: cannot convert ‘time_t*’ to ‘void**’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int timer_create(clockid_t, sigevent*, void**)’

Tags: c, linux, timer, g++

I have written a simple timer function and compiled in g++, and strangely it is asking that the prototype of timer_create is: `int timer_create(clockid_t, sigevent*, void**)`, which is not true.

My code is shown below.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sig_handlerTimer1(int,siginfo_t*,void*);
time_t timerid;
int main()
{
     int i;
static struct sigaction sa;


static struct sigevent sevp;  // argument to timer_create
static struct itimerspec its; // argument to timer_gettime

memset (&sevp, 0, sizeof (struct sigevent));
sevp.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
sevp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
sevp.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;
sevp.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;

/* Setting timer interval */
its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

/* Setting timer expiration */
its.it_value.tv_sec = 2;  // First expiry after 1 sec
its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

/* Setting the signal handlers before invoking timer*/
sa.sa_sigaction = sig_handlerTimer1;
sa.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sevp, &timerid) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "LeakTracer (timer_trackStartTime): timer_create failed to create timer. " \
        "Leak measurement will be for entire duration of the execution period:%s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;

}

if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "LeakTracer (timer_trackStartTime): timer_settime failed to set the timer. " \
        "Leak measurement will be for entire duration of execution period:%s \n", strerror(errno));
    return 0;

}

   for(i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
     printf("%d\n",i);
     sleep(1);
   }
  }

  void sig_handlerTimer1(int signum,siginfo_t* si, void* au)
  {

   int flag = 1;
   printf("Caught signal: %d\n",signum);
   if (timer_delete(&timerid) < 0)
   {
            fprintf(stderr, "timer deletion failed. " \
        "This may result in some memory leaks (sig_handlerTimer1):%s \n", strerror(errno));
   }
  }
```

Errors:

```
enter code here
#  g++ signalTimer.cc -lrt

signalTimer.cc: In function ‘int main()’:

signalTimer.cc:40: error: cannot convert ‘time_t*’ to ‘void**’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int timer_create(clockid_t, sigevent*, void**)’

signalTimer.cc:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘time_t’ to ‘void*’

signalTimer.cc:48: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int timer_settime(void*, int, const itimerspec*, itimerspec*)’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `timer_t`, not a `time_t`.

(The reason you get the obscure message is because a `timer_t` is actually a `void *`, once you've followed all the `typedef`s.)

Comment: Then how come in C it is compiling?

Comment: [root@raj prototype]# ./a.out 

0

1

Caught signal: 10

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x08049ea0 ***

======= Backtrace: =========

/lib/libc.so.6[0x6fc595]

/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0x6fc9d9]

/lib/librt.so.1(timer_delete+0x42)[0xa814e2]./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x334)[0x804899c]
[0xdbd420]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x2ea)[0x8048952]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0x6a8e9c]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x39)[0x80486a1]
======= Memory map: ========
00670000-0068a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 29263039   /lib/ld-2.5.so

Comment: @kingsmasher: In GCC, you should get a warning about "assignment from incompatible pointer type", which is invalid in C++.

Comment: @kingsmasher: Those error messages are probably from an unrelated problem, which you will need to fix (or create a new question for).

Comment: I got the reason, in `timer_delete` i was passing, a pointer, instead of timerid. Thank You, the question is closed.